# How to use CSS sprites within a responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm hoping there will be a CSS guru out there that can help with this one...
I'm building a responsive layout for a site which includes a horizontal navigation bar across the top. This bar contains 5 buttons each of the same width (although obviously this width needs to be flexible). I would like to use icons instead of text for the buttons for when the menu is viewed on a device with a small viewport width. I will use media queries to adapt the layout to use text once I feel the viewport width has reached a suitable size. This is important because I am not anticipating needing to change the size of the icons themselves. I'm happy for them to be of a fixed size, centered in the button and if the button size itself changes then there will simply be more "padding" around the centered icon.
Ordinarily I would use have all the icons in one image and use the sprite technique to only display the correct part of the image, but I have come across a problem. If I want the anchor element to fill the parent list element then how can I center the sprite?

Here is some example markup:
First the html (snippet)

```
 <nav>
   <ul class="top_nav">
    <li><a class="link_1" href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="link_2" href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="link_3" href="#">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="link_4" href="#">link 4</a></li>
    <li><a class="link_5" href="#">link 5</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

And I might style it like this:

```
 nav ul {
          width: 100%;
          overflow: auto;
        }

 nav li {
          float: left;
          width: 20%;
          background: #2c2c2c; /* dark background for light icons */
        }

 nav li a {
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            background-image: url(path/to/sprite.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            text-indent: -15000px;
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
            margin: 0 auto;
          }

 nav li a.link_1 {
                   background-position: 0 0;
                 }

 nav li a.link_2 {
                   background-position: 0 -49px;
                 }
```

etc....

But this will only give me a clickable area of 48px x 48px within a button that can change it's width depending on the size of the parent element. If I make the anchor element fill it's parent list element then the icon can't be centered using the margin rule.
I could add another element inside the anchor element which was empty but had the icon as it's background like this:

```
 <li><a href="#"><div class="link_1">Link 1</div></a></li>
```

And style it with:

```
 nav li a {
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            width: 100%;
          }

 nav li a div {
                background-image: url(path/to/sprite.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                text-indent: -15000px;
                width: 48px;
                height: 48px;
                margin: 0 auto;
              }

 nav li a div.link_1 {
                   background-position: 0 0;
                 }
```

But this isn't a very semantic or elegant solution. Can anyone think of anything better??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

- generated content (`:before`/`:after`) instead of real elements to keep code clean;
- [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) property to zoom your background images;
- [Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs) instead of sprites. Data URIs are supported by all current browsers (IE8 has 32KB limitation of maximum size for each file represented as a Data URI).

Comment: Can you post the code for your solution?  I am having a similar issue. Thank you!

Comment: How does the first option `:before/:after` solve the issue of responsive css sprites (aka a scaling background)? Could you provide code?

Answer (score 3):

I've created a [responsive CSS sprite generator](http://responsive-css.spritegen.com/).

It works using transparent PNGs in data URIs to keep the aspect ratio, a percentage background-position to show the right image, and background-sizing: 100% to scale it.

Unlike some of the other techniques out there, this will work with images of different sizes and aspect ratios in a single sprite.

Answer (score 2):

I actually have a solution that has great cross-browser support, has nice clean code, and is well documented for using sprites as a background image with a little css markup over at my blog here: http://pagecrafter.com/responsive-background-image-sprites-css-tutorial/

Essentially it relies on a neat trick to maintain the aspect ratio of an element, while allowing the background image to stay the full size of said element. Then all that's needed is to specify the location of the background sprite in percents! This method works well too, because once you have the css ready, you just apply a class to your element and you are good to go.

Comment: Link broken, is it [this one](http://blog.brianjohnsondesign.com/responsive-background-image-sprites-css-tutorial/) now?